# ExceptionInInitializerError, org.hibernate.MappingException: invalid configuration

Tags: java, hibernate, intellij-idea

Знакомлюсь с *hibernate*, и никак не получается сделать даже простое приложение: постоянно какие-либо ошибки. С библиотеками уже разобрался, но всё равно не работает.

[Ссылка на проект](https://yadi.sk/d/rbmcoYfFhoUsr)

Ошибка:

```
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.MappingException: invalid configuration
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at util.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:16)
at DAO.AuthorDAOImpl.addAuthor(AuthorDAOImpl.java:20)
at logic.Main.main(Main.java:11)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: invalid configuration
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2018)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1993)
at util.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:13)
... 7 more
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 25; Document is invalid: no grammar found.
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:437)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:368)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:325)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:228)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:605)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3138)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:880)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:117)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:649)
at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:465)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2015)
... 9 more
```

Comment: Конфиг от Hibernate не мешало бы добавить в вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

> Постоянно какие либо ошибки, вроде с библиотеками уже разобрался, но всё равно не работает.

Это нормально. В Java, помимо просто синтаксиса, есть куча соглашений и неявных правил, которые со временем утрясутся в голове. К сожалению, в языке есть некоторый пробел между уровнем входящего и более-менее разбирающегося спеца, многие материалы нацелены на людей, которые понимают в происходящее всё, кроме того, что разбирается непосредственно в материале.

Конкретно у вас ошибка происходит при чтении xml-файла, но я не могу сказать, какого - я не знаю, как запускать проект, а собрать его не смог, потому что мой мавен не может найти артефакт **com.oracle.adf:adf-parent:pom:12.1.3-0-0**. В проблемном XML-файле допущена ошибка в синтаксисе, во всяком случае, SAX-парсер не справился и упал в этом месте.

Точный контекст падения вы сможете узнать, поставив точку останову на строчке вызова исключения (дважды блямкнуть <kbd>Shift</kbd> - ввести `XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl` - перейти в декомпилированный исходник и скачать полный по желанию - щелкнуть на левой серой полосе редактора на строке **228**) и запустив то, что вы запускаете, в режиме дебага (для этого нужно создать *run configuration*, которую затем запустить в режиме дебага, <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>f9</kbd>). Там у вас будет доступ к *call stack*, в котором можно будет обнаружить хвосты проблемы.

Что до хранения кода, то рекомендую использовать github или bitbucket, и не хранить папки-файлы `.idea`, `.iml`, `target` и прочие производные проекта - они воссоздаются на любой машине. В идеальном случае на гитхабе вам могут прислать исправление прямо в репозиторий. Однако, хочу сказать, что здесь не приветствуются общие вопросы, поэтому, на самом деле, проект не надо  прикладывать никогда - здесь нужно задавать конкретные вопросы, например "У меня падает программа при *%таком-то%* запуске с исключением `SAXException`" - т.е. здесь разбираются конкретные вопросы по конкретным проблемам. Общий Code Review все довольно давно хотели бы видеть, но такого русскоязычного сервиса у нас пока нет.